# Two URLs, Same Server / Files?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I would like to have two URL (ex: www.mycoolsite.com and www.myfunsite.com) and point them to the same server, and use some of the same files. I want a different homepage and css for each site, but evernthing else would be identical.

My webhost allows me to 'park' a domain, but that changes the URL that the user sees and I'm not sure if there is anyway to detect which URL the user originally entered.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: What kind of web hosting do you use? Do you have access to web server configuration? If yes, what server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a HTTP 301 permanent redirect.
[Example](http://www.somacon.com/p145.php)

Comment: Looks like an apache mod_rewrite will work if I use [L] instead of [R]